# I want to minus a current date or now date with last 12 weeks and keep TZ format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am not sure how to start and have been pointed to https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html

The example has this thread:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2013-05-08') AS v1, DATEADD(year, 2, TO_DATE('2013-05-08')) AS v;
```

So this works:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2013-05-08') AS v1, DATEADD(week, -12, TO_DATE('2013-05-08')) AS v;
```

But what I am running into is selecting TZ format and the results are just giving me the date:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z') AS v1, DATEADD(week, -12, TO_DATE('2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z')) AS v;
```

These are my results:

```
Row   V1          V
1     2011-08-12  2011-05-20
```

I want these results

```
Row         V1                       V
1          2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z  2011-05-20T20:17:46.384Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
alter session set TIMESTAMP_NTZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FF3Z';

SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z') AS v1, DATEADD(week, -12, TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z')) AS v;
```